# Sharing Hotspot from the mac that the iPhone or iPad can connect with?

Tags: network, wifi, development, tethering

Is it possible to share a kind of "hotspot" from my macbook so that the iPhone and iPad can connect with it? Just like there is a "personal hotspot" feature on the iPhone I want it the other way around.

The reason I'm asking is that I'm in a room where I have absolutely NO internet. Wheter 3G on my iPhone nor any wireless or ethernet connection.

Is there any chance I can create my own "internal" wireless network outgoing of my mac and connect my iPhone and iPad with it so that it has a regular IP etc.

I need this because I want to demo a Website that is built for mobile devices. I have a local apache server on my mac and usually develop and test with "Adobe Shadow" (meanwhile [Adobe Edge Inspect](http://html.adobe.com/edge/inspect/)). This works great usuaslly when all my devices are in the same network. However in this room there is no network so I wonder how I could create my own network.

Any ideas about that?

Answer (score 3):

You can create a Personal Network from the AirPort (Wi-Fi) menu.

1. Select *Create Network ...*
2. Define a name for your Network
3. Select the channel
4. Select the security (if selected, define a passphrase/key)
5. Click *Create*.

[image]

In my case I also have to define the IP addresses on the devices.

On your MacBook:

1. Go to *System Preferences*
2. *Network*
3. Select the *Wi-Fi* connection
4. Click *Advanced*
5. Select the tab *TCP/IP*
6. In the first field select the voice *Manually*
7. Set an IP (e.g. 192.168.1.1)
8. Set a Subnet Mask (255.255.255.0)
9. Click *OK*

On the iOS devices:

1. Go to *Settings*
2. *Wi-Fi*
3. Click the blue arrow on the righ of your ad hoc Wi-Fi connection
4. Select the tab *Static*
5. Set an IP (e.g. 192.168.1.2)
6. Set a Subnet Mask (255.255.255.0)

Comment: I did everything described above, but somehow my devices still will not be able to use the internet connection. The wifi icon is visible in the iphone, however if I try to visit a website or something, I receive a pop-up saying that I have no connection to the internet. Does anybody have some additional tips? Cheers.

Comment: @marieke1981 The instruction above are not for sharing Internet, but for creating a wireless network. If you want to share Internet connect the Ethernet cable to your Mac. Than go to `System Preferences`->`Sharing` and enable `Internet Sharing`. You have to configure it. It should be easy.